# adapter: mysql2 to adapter: mysql difference?

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra

When create database on my CentOS 6.5 system, i got this error:

```
 [william@qwe current]$ bundle exec rake db:create RACK_ENV=production --trace
    ** Invoke db:create (first_time)
    ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
    ** Execute db:load_config
    "-----------------Redis.rb"
    ** Execute db:create
    Character set 'utf8mb4' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
    Couldn't create database for {"database"=>"fsproduction", "encoding"=>"utf8mb4", "adapter"=>"mysql2", "username"=>"root", "password"=>"123", "host"=>"localhost", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "socket"=>"/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"}, {:charset=>"utf8mb4"}
    (If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

Here is my database.yml. But i change `adapter: mysql2` to `adapter: mysql` it works.

```
production:
  database: fsproduction
  encoding: utf8mb4
  adapter: mysql2
  username: root
  password: '123'
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Any clue for this, thanks!!
--------**update**-------------

what's `adapter: mysql2` and `adapter: mysql` difference ?

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You should be using `mysql2`. It's possible that the old `mysql` driver doesn't understand the encoding directive you've given and ignores it. Check that your table encoding is set correctly.

Comment: I attached my char set it correct. Why should i use mysql2 and if i change to mysql why it works ?

Comment: `mysql2` is still actively supported. `mysql` is provided for legacy reasons only, it was last updated in 2013. If you've found a bug, might be worth reporting it, raising an issue on the [project page](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2).